# How to write jquery code within php code

Tags: php, mysql

Hello, I would like to add some JQuery code when my MySQL query match a specific ID, here is my code:

```
<?php
$chkgreenmark ="select * from TABLE where PARAM = '$VARIABLE'";
$sqlchkgreenmark = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['mysqli'],$chkgreenmark);
$numsqlchkgreenmark = mysqli_num_rows($sqlchkgreenmark);
if($numsqlchkgreenmark > 0) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".calendercolumn .dragbox #dragID").append("<div class='detailssaved'><a href='#' ><img src='./images/check_mark.JPG' height='15' width='15'></a></div>");
</script>
<?php 
}?>
```

The problem is that I get the JQuery code even when I don't have any result.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens?

Comment: try to echo $numsqlchkgreenmark first to see if it is returning correct results.. the issue has nothing to do with javascript code, it is fine, even the condition statement, you query has some issue try to print mysqli errors, what is $GLOBALS['mysqli'] ?

Comment: @Foxish It's still inside the if statement.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?php
    $chkgreenmark ="select * from TABLE where PARAM = '$VARIABLE'";
    $sqlchkgreenmark = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['mysqli'],$chkgreenmark);
    $numsqlchkgreenmark = mysqli_num_rows($sqlchkgreenmark);
    if($numsqlchkgreenmark > 0)
    {
          echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            $(".calendercolumn .dragbox #dragID").append("<div class=\'detailssaved\'><a href=\'#\' ><img src=\'./images/check_mark.JPG\' height=\'15\' width=\'15\'></a></div>");
          </script>';
    }
?>
```

[Live Demo](http://codepad.org/5UkEW7RI)

Answer (score 0):

I tried @rynhe answer, but didn't work for me until i added the **Document Ready function**

```
<?php
    $chkgreenmark ="select * from TABLE where PARAM = '$VARIABLE'";
    $sqlchkgreenmark = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['mysqli'],$chkgreenmark);
    $numsqlchkgreenmark = mysqli_num_rows($sqlchkgreenmark);
    if($numsqlchkgreenmark > 0)
    {
          echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(e) {
                     $(".calendercolumn .dragbox #dragID").append("<div class=\'detailssaved\'><a href=\'#\' ><img src=\'./images/check_mark.JPG\' height=\'15\' width=\'15\'></a></div>");
                });
          </script>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

on php files or pages that u can use php tags , u can write php into jquery scripts. So that u can use it like below;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".calendercolumn .dragbox <?php echo $id;?>").append("<div class='detailssaved'><a href='#' ><img src='./images/check_mark.JPG' height='15' width='15'></a></div>");
</script>
```